# How to display a dropdown -customer attribute- in customer registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-attribute

I still cannot figure out how to display the dropdown on the customer registration form at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Any ideas how?

Setup file:

```
    <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customer_group",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Customer Group",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "customerattribute/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions15505846310",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "Business",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customer_group");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Source file:

```
<?php
class CustomerAttribute_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Customeroptions15505846310 extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Business"),
                    "value" =>  1
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Personal"),
                    "value" =>  2
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Institution"),
                    "value" =>  3
                ),

            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Column(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $columns = array();
        $columns[$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()] = array(
            "type"      => "tinyint(1)",
            "unsigned"  => false,
            "is_null"   => true,
            "default"   => null,
            "extra"     => null
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Indexes(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = array();

        $index = "IDX_" . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = array(
            "type"      => "index",
            "fields"    => array($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())
        );

        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return Varien_Db_Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute")
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

Added dropdown input with your custom option. Magento can't automatically create the form for the frontend.

In your case:

```
<select name="customer_group" id="customer_group">
    <option value="1"><?php echo $this->__('Business')?></option>
    <option value="2"><?php echo $this->__('Personal')?></option>
    <option value="3"><?php echo $this->__('Institution')?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Sohel; i understand this, but how can I be sure that the selected value would update the value that has been previously set for the customer at the backend?

Comment: Registration is not for a new customer? How you set the value before registration?

Comment: The module has a default value; but the meaning is that customers can edit it when registering, or when accessing the customer account page or when checking out.